# How to return pattern-matched element?

Tags: scala

I want to match a `String` returned from `someFunction` and have the default case return the `String` from the `someFunction`.

```
someFunction(input) match {
  case "123" => "234"
  case "234" => "345"
  case _ => _
}
```

Where `case _ => _` returns what `someFunction(input)` actually returns. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to name the default case:

```
someFunction(input) match {
  case "123" => "234"
  case "234" => "345"
  case x => x
}
```